# curl with ssl support API does not return

Tags: ssl, openssl, arm, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I use `simplessl.c` to check 2-way SSL with self signed certs. I passed all the certs paths like CA,client. When I ran the application on linux x86 it worked well. But when i ran it on ARM board,the application didn't go ahead of `curl_easy_perform()`. I even checked the equivalent command line; the command also does not return. Why is this behavior?

How does **curl** calculate the time on ARM board, is this same way **openssl** calculates? When I run the command `openssl s_client -connect .....` it showed the cert is not yet valid (which is because of no RTC on ARM ) and the time on ARM board shows Jan 1 1970. So,I set date manually, now it worked.

But curl command line or `curl_easy_perform()` API still does not work!

Comment: This question is related to programming so please don't migrate it to superuser.

Comment: @Artles noise...I guess, i didn't say the issue is only because of ARM.There are other tags also which may not be root cause of problem.Thanks.

Comment: To further add up to my issue, I checked the TCP server with SSL enabled on ARM board, and ran the libcurl http client on linux x86.For the first time it did n't work. Then again, I set the date on ARM board.It worked. (I guess,that's because the TCP server uses openssl APIs directly ).                                          Now again I tried the same apps,this time server on linux x86 libcurl http client on ARM.The same issue reproduced!! The issue clearly seems to be with curl validating the client certificate with RTC time as reference.